# How to convert JSON field name to Java bean class property with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have access to a RESTful API which returns JSON Strings, such as the following:

```
{
    "Container1": {
        "active": true
    },
    "Container2": {
        "active": false
    },
}
```

The problem is that the RESTful API is a bit maldesigned. The field name contains the data already. With the Jackson library it is not possible to deserialize the field name to a property name of the corresponding Java bean class. I assume, this isn't intended by the JSON specification neither. The above JSON string needs to be deserialized to an instance of the following class:

```java
public class Container {
    private Boolean active;
    private String name;
}
```

I end up with `UnrecognizedPropertyException` for the field `Container1`.

I thought to configure to ignore unknown properties and to provide a `JsonDeserializer` for that property like this:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Container {
    private Boolean active;
    private String name;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = FieldNameToPropertyDeserializer.class)
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and the `FieldNameToPropertyDeserializer`:

```java
public class FieldNameToPropertyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {
    public FieldNameToPropertyDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return parser.getCurrentName();
    }
}
```

The invocation of the deserialization is achieved as follows:

```java
String jsonString = response.readEntity(String.class);
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectReader readerFor = objectMapper.readerFor(Container.class);
MappingIterator<Container> mappingIterator = readerFor.readValues(jsonString);
while (mappingIterator.hasNext()) {
    Container container = (Container) mappingIterator.next();
    containers.add(container);
}
```

But I only receive empty objects (properties set to `null`) because the parsing of the properties is skipped since I set `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`.

Is this possible at all? Or should I implement something like a post-processing afterwards?

Comment: Jackson – Change Name of Field- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-name-of-property

Comment: @ErnstZ is it possible that you would get more containers as response , e.g. Container3 and so on ? Or is the suffix finite ?

Comment: Yes, more containers are possible and they could have any name. The pattern `ContainerX` is only an example.

Comment: @Dulaj: this is not exactly what I meant. My problem is that I don't know the field name in advance. It might be any string.

Comment: @ErnstZ Great and Impress

Comment: Up vote from me Because of  it is very impressive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick solution, if the object is such that, that all of it object is a container object you can receive the JSON inside and JSONObject you may use below code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestSO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, JSONException, IOException {
        String jsonString = "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"Container1\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"active\": true\r\n" + 
                "    },\r\n" + 
                "    \"Container2\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"active\": false\r\n" + 
                "    },\r\n" + 
                "}";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        for (String key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
            Container container = mapper.readValue(jsonObject.get(key).toString(), Container.class);
            System.out.println(container);
        }   
    }

    static class Container{
        private String name;
        private Boolean active;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Boolean getActive() {
            return active;
        }
        public void setActive(Boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Container [name=" + name + ", active=" + active + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like to use `JSONObject` since you have field name and content logically together. But your solution doesn't automatically deserialize the field name to an object's property. After unmarshalling to the `Container` instance you need to invoke `container.setName(key)`. In addition, one more dependency is required: `org.json`, but that's ok for me. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I accept this contribution as solution because it matches my expectations best since only one addition needs to be realised in order to have the desired result:
```java
container.setName(key)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this. Create a class ContainerActive like this

```
public class ContainerActive {
    private  boolean active;
    // constructors, setters, getters
}
```

And you could just do

```
  Map<String, ContainerActive> map = mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Map<String, ContainerActive>>() {});
```

With this you will have "Container1", "Container2" as the keys and ContainerActive Object as values which has active field.

Comment: Yes, this is also an alternative for mapping field name to the particular object. Drawback is that the `name` property must be set afterwards, similar to the provided solution from @Hades.

Comment: Yes. You have to . Because your json is not really according to the standard